# Result goes blank in highchart

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, highcharts

I am using highchart with codeigniter. And I got some reference from blueflame. Here is my code that gives the result blank.
When I am going to run, it shows blank result. Where I have to change to get the result properly.

Controller:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Chart extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Data');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //echo "adsf";exit;
        $this->load->view('chart_view');
    }

    public function data()
    {
        $result = $this->Data->get_data();

        $category = array();
        $category['name'] = 'Category';

        $series1 = array();
        $series1['id'] = 'ebay_token';

        $series2 = array();
        $series2['id'] = 'development_id';

        $series3 = array();
        $series3['id'] = 'application_id';

        $series4 = array();
        $series4['id'] = 'certification_id';

        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            $category['result'][] = $row->ebay_token;
            $category['result'][] = $row->development_id;
            $category['result'][] = $row->application_id;
            $category['result'][] = $row->certification_id;
        }

        $final = array();
        array_push($final,$category);
        array_push($final,$series1);
        array_push($final,$series2);
        array_push($final,$series3);
        array_push($final,$series4);

        print json_encode($final, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
<?php
    class Data extends CI_Model
    {
        public function __construct() 
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function get_data()
        {
            $this->db->select('ebay_token,application_id,development_id,certification_id');
            $this->db->from('ebay_configuration');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }

    }
```

View:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            var options = 
            {
                chart: 
                {
                    renderTo: 'chartcon',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: 
                {
                    text: 'Project Requests',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: 
                {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: 
                {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: 
                {
                    title: 
                    {
                        text: 'Requests'
                    },
                    plotLines: 
                    [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: 
                {
                    formatter: function() 
                    {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.id +'</b>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: 
                {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

                series: []
            }

            $.getJSON("result", function(json) 
            {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['result'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                options.series[2] = json[3];
                options.series[3] = json[4];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="chartcon" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Comment: What does your JSON return ? What is the format of `json[1]` e.g.

Comment: It will give the result of series. See this, print json_encode($final, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: We mean how your JSON looks like, could you paste your JSON here?